# MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators fires Invoked event twice

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have implemented `MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators` and below you can see the code

Xaml code

```
        <Button Content="Edit Options"
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="FlyoutItem1" Text="Copy" Icon="Copy">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator x:Name="Test" Key="C" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="Test_Invoked" />
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Code-Behind

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Test_Invoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> invoked Hash = {sender.GetHashCode()}");
    }
}
```

Before clicking on the button in the application, the CTRL+C hotkey action fires an event. But when I click on the button and **MenuFlyout** appears, the Ctrl+C hotkey action fires twice the same event. And when I click on another place in the application event again fires normally only once.

---

If you want to test the application follow this link
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ef4qnFnbvDj4J5rUoUVpot8Eqx077i9w/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: for this problem, please send feedback with windows feedback hub app.

Comment: We have already sent the feedback via this app thanks a lot to You. The title is "MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators fires Invoked event twice"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will keep follow up this one, if there is any updates , I will comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mircrosoft Documentation about KeyboardAccelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyboardaccelerator?view=winrt-22000)

> By default, an accelerator has global scope. However, you can constrain scope using ScopeOwner or disable an accelerator completely using IsEnabled.

I don't know is this a bug or just a behavior that they haven't described on their documentation but if you got more than one KeyboardAccelerator in the same scope then it fires twice if you are focused on the element that contains KeyboardAccelerator.

**Solution.**

So in your case you need to specify scope for KeyboardAccelerator and it will fire only once in that scope.

**Important!**

You need to bind ScopeOwner only using x:Bind. It won't work with Binding.

```
<Button Content="Edit Options"
        x:Name="button"
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="FlyoutItem1" Text="Copy" Icon="Copy">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator x:Name="Test" Key="C" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="Test_Invoked" ScopeOwner="{x:Bind button}" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to set args.Handled = true in the Test_Invoked function like this:

```
private void Test_Invoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> invoked Hash = {sender.GetHashCode()}");
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

My similar problem is solved [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1145063/how-to-make-keyboardaccelerator39s-event-handler-o.html).